# httparty issue when running a GET

Tags: ruby, authorization, httparty

I have this basic piece of code which doesn't work properly.

If I run the following I get:

".rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/multi_xml-0.5.5/lib/multi_xml/parsers/rexml.rb:18:in `parse': The document "The supplied authentication is invalid" does not have a valid root (MultiXml::ParseError)"

---

```
class Temp
  include HTTParty
  format :xml 

  def initialize()
    self.class.base_uri "https://beta2014.vchs.vmware.com"
  end

  def login(username, password)
    self.class.basic_auth username, password
    self.class.default_options[:headers] = {"Accept" => "application/xml;version=5.7"}
    response = self.class.post('/api/iam/login')
    # setting global cookie var to be used later on
    @cookie = response.headers['vchs-authorization']
    return @cookie
  end  

  def plans(token)
    token = 'Bearer ' + token
    self.class.base_uri "https://beta2014.vchs.vmware.com"
    self.class.default_options[:headers] = { 'Accept' => "application/xml;class=com.vmware.vchs.iam.api.schema.v2.classes.user.Users;version=5.7", 'Authorization' => token }
    response = self.class.get('/api/sc/plans')
  end
end #class Temp

temp = Temp.new()      
token = temp.login(username, password)
temp.plans(token)
```

---

The token has the right content. I know that because if I "puts" the value of the token and copy&paste it into a REST client it works just fine.

Interestingly enough, if I generate the token on the REST client and I statically set the token with `token = <string>` (instead of calling `temp.login`) the call `temp.plans` works just fine and I get my proper response.

I have also tried to do:

```
tokendummy = temp.login(username, password)
token = <string>
```

and it fails again.

It's like if `token.plans` works only if it's the first method being called. If it's the second (after `temp.login`) it fails.

Does it have something to do with the `initialize()` method that is only being called the first time?

Comment: I apologize the code snippet has been horribly formatted (for some reasons).

Comment: The way I set the token manually is with "token = <string>"

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. You need to use the {} button or indentation for code formatting when posting/editing a Question or Answer.

Comment: As I keep driving up this wall, I am getting closer to the problem but still can't see how to fix it. Apparently the offending line is `self.class.basic_auth username, password` in the login method. If I comment out that line, temp.plans works fine even if temp.login is called first. There seems to be an incompatibility between basic_auth and the "Authorizaion" header with the token. I tried to clean up basic_auth calling `self.class.basic_auth nil, nil` but it doesn't like it. Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: For the records I have tactically by-passed the problem so far by splitting the different calls into two different classes (which works as they are different objects not tied together). It is not a bad workaround as it maps fine/ok the phisolophy behind the tool I am building.